# Bounded holomorphic section

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Is it possible that there exists a multivalued holomorphic
function $\phi\not \equiv 0$ from $\mathbb {CP}^1$ to $\mathbb C^k$ that has monodromies
$A_1, \dots A_n \in GL_k(\mathbb C)$
around points $u_1, \dots u_n$ respectively such that two properties hold

1. $A_j ^3 = \operatorname{Id}$ for every $j$;
2. $\phi(z) = o(1)$ for $z$ near any $u_j$?

   Remark: due to property (1)
   $\phi$ is a single-valued function
   of $\sqrt[3]{z-u_j}$ near $u_j$. The second property means that this single-valued function has no pole at $z= u_j$.